# Can I disable Fullscreen Video Playing on iPhone's Safari browser?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, youtube-api

I created a webpage, in which users can plays youtube video and watch it.

It works perfectly with Safari(MacOSX, iPad), Android's default browser, and any kind of browsers(For Windows).

However, only Safari with iPhone(or iPod touch) forces it to start playing with fullscreen.
I've already tried with iOS6.x, and all of them force it play with fullscreen.

How can I avoid fullscreen playing? 
I gave it a try to add this attribute `playsinline` but it didn't do any...

This is my code and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffposnick/u6SZp/). I need your help. Thanks!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script>
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
          playerVars: {
            playsinline: 1
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```